# I don't understand this rock paper scissors game

Tags: python-3.x

I found this code, and I'm having trouble understanding the lines 'user_hand = rps[int(user_input) - 1]' , 'com_hand = choice(rps)' , ' if rps_dict[user_hand]['strong'] == com_hand:' , 'print_result(**game_result)' , ' 
Why should I subtract 1 from user_input? Why put rps inside brackets next to choice? Why do you win 'if rps_dict[user_hand]['strong'] == com_hand ? Why if user_hand equal to com_hand? It doesnt make sense to me.. I know '**game_result' means it's a kwark, but I dont know why I need to declare it as a kwarg. I'm sorry if these questions seem stupid, but I'm frustrated.

```
from random import choice

rps = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
rps_dict = {
'rock': {'strong': 'scissors', 'weak': 'paper'},
'paper': {'strong': 'rock', 'weak': 'scissors'},
'scissors': {'strong': 'paper', 'weak': 'rock'}
}


def print_result(user_score, com_score, win, lose, tie):
    print('Result:', end=' ')
    if user_score > com_score:
        print('You win!')
    elif user_score < com_score:
        print('You lose...')
    else:
        print('Draw.')
    print('--------------------')
    # Print scores
    print(f'Your score: {user_score}')
    print(f'Computer score: {com_score}')
    print('--------------------')
    # Print statistics
    print(f'Win: {win}')
    print(f'Lose: {lose}')
    print(f'Tie: {tie}')


def play(rounds):
    game_result = {
    'user_score': 0,
    'com_score': 0,
    'win': 0,
    'lose': 0, 
    'tie': 0
    }
while rounds > 0:
    user_input = input(
    'Enter your choice (1: Rock, 2: Paper, 3: Scissors, 0: Quit): ')
    # Check whether the input is in the options
    if user_input in ('1', '2', '3'):
        rounds -= 1
        user_hand = rps[int(user_input) - 1]
        com_hand = choice(rps)
        # user_hand is strong against com_hand
        if rps_dict[user_hand]['strong'] == com_hand:
            game_result['user_score'] += 1
            game_result['win'] += 1
            result = 'You win!'
            # user_hand is weak against com_hand
        elif rps_dict[user_hand]['weak'] == com_hand:
            game_result['com_score'] += 1
            game_result['lose'] += 1
            result = 'You lose...'
            # Tie
        else:
            game_result['tie'] += 1
            result = 'Tie.'
        print(
            f'You -> {user_hand}. Computer -> {com_hand}. {result}')
    elif user_input == '0':
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid input!')
    print()
print_result(**game_result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissors Game!')
    try:
        rounds = int(input('How many rounds you want to play? '))
        play(rounds)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please input a valid number!')
```

Comment: User is asked to chose an option 1, 2 or 3. Python lists are indexed from 0 so the list will be indexed as 0, 1, 2. So if the user chooses 1, its really index 0 in the list. So you subtract one from the user input to be able to get the appropriate item from the list

Comment: `choice` selects a random entry of the tuple `rps`. In `rps_dict` you have which selection wins (strong and weak). `==` doesn't set but checks for equality

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, and I'll do my best to discuss the lines that you said you have trouble with:

`user_hand = rps[int(user_input) - 1]`
The user_hand variable is used to store the choice the user inputs. user_input is the text the user directley entered. This will be saved as a string, so the code stransforms it into an integer with the int class. Next, it subtracts one from the user input (computers count from zero rather than 1). Then, it grabs the element from the list that  has that index. For example, if I entered one, it would grab the list item at index 0 ("rock").

`com_hand = choice(rps)`
This line here is used to gather the computer's choice. As you can see from the first line, the choice function from the random module is imported directly. This allows you to use the function without specifying the module it came from. The choice function selects a random item from the specified list, which is the same rps list as before.

`if rps_dict[user_hand]['strong'] == com_hand:`
The if statement here gathers data from the rps_dict and compares it to the computer's hand. The rps_dict is a dictionary that contains data on which hand beats or loses to another. To translate the if statement into simpler english, it means if the hand the user's hand would beat (which can be found with rps_dict[user_hand]["strong"]), is the computer's hand, the user will win. In addition, to avoid confusion, the == operator check's for equality, and doesn't assign the variable to com_hand.

`print_result(**game_result)`
Here you said that you don't understand why the parameters are passed in this way. You don't really need to do it in this format, but the person who created the script decided to (possibly as it is simpler to read).

Thank you, and if you have any other questions, please comment and I'll do my best to answer them!

Comment: Thanks @PYer! Your answer is very helpful to me. Though I still have a hard time understanding why the programmer wrote 'if rps_dict[user_hand]['strong'] == com_hand:'. Why must I write 'equal to' instead of 'greater than'? it would make more sense to me by writing 'greater than', in case the user wins.

Comment: about 'print_result(**game_result)', I might need to dig deeper into *args and **kwargs, cause although I have studied it before, it's still quite a hard concept for me to master. I have learned python since a year and a half, but I keep forgetting concepts like args, kwargs, self, and more. maybe I need to put even more time into it

Comment: `rps_dict[user_hand]['strong']` get's the string holding the hand that will be beaten. If the computer hand "is equal to" the hand that can be beaten, it is then beaten. For example, if I inputed 1 for "rock", `rps_dict[user_hand]['strong']` would return "scissors". Therefore, if the computer hand is "scissors", I would beat the computer. Does that make sense?

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, if I input 1 for 'rock',  'strong' or 'weak' are equal to what the computer choses? or in other words, if the computer choses 'scissors' (which is the value of 'strong' in this case) I win? and if computer choses 'paper' (which is the value of 'weak' in this case) I lose?